# как проверить что бот является админом в указаном канале или группе по ссылке?

Tags: python, aiogram

как проверить что бот является админом в указаном канале или группе по ссылке
чтобы при команде с ссылкой в чате проверялась если можео скиньте функцию? aiogram

Comment: то есть вы отправляйте в бота ссылку на группу, а бот должен вернуть результат, является ли он админом, или нет?

Comment: только не в боте а в группе